# Removing strings based on other strings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| JELLY ROSEN 15 JELLY STREET APT 111 JERSEY CITY, NJ | 15 JELLY STREET APT 111 JERSEY CITY, NJ |
| ROB ROSEN & STEVEN ROSEN 29 MAIN ST JERSEY CITY, NJ | 29 MAIN ST JERSEY CITY, NJ |

I need the following:
|** Column C  ** |
| JELLY ROSEN|
| ROB ROSEN & STEVEN ROSEN|

I've tried something like this:

```
def address_name(COLUMN A, COLUMN B):
    return df['COLUMN A'][:df['COLUMN A'][0].find(df['COLUMN B'][0])]
```

Comment: What specific issues did you have with what you tried?

Comment: Sure. When I try to run the below
df['COLUMN C'] = df.apply(lambda x: address_name(df['COLUMN A'], df['COLUMN B']), axis=1)

I'm getting a Key error: 'COLUMN C' as well as Value Error ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (22640, 27)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below function to get the values into column c

```py
def replace_values(x):
    cola, colb = x
    return cola.replace(colb,'')

df['Column C'] = df[['Column A', 'Column B']].apply(replace_values, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex :

```
import re
df["COLUMN C"] = list(map(lambda x: re.match(r"([^0-9]+)",x,re.I).groups()[0][:-1],df["COLUMN A"]))
```